# Pagination drop down not working react-bootstrap-table2

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap-table

I am using react-bootstrap-table2 and cannot get the pagination drop down working.

See my options:

```js
        const options = {
            paginationSize: 4,
            pageStartIndex: 0,
            //alwaysShowAllBtns: true, // Always show next and previous button
            //withFirstAndLast: false, // Hide the going to First and Last page button
            // hideSizePerPage: true, // Hide the sizePerPage dropdown always
            // hidePageListOnlyOnePage: true, // Hide the pagination list when only one page
            firstPageText: 'First',
            prePageText: 'Back',
            nextPageText: 'Next',
            lastPageText: 'Last',
            nextPageTitle: 'First page',
            prePageTitle: 'Pre page',
            firstPageTitle: 'Next page',
            lastPageTitle: 'Last page',
            sizePerPageList: [{
                text: '5', value: 5
            },{
                text: '10', value: 10
            },{
                text: 'All', value: this.state.currentlyDisplayed.length
            }] // A numeric array is also available. the purpose of above example is custom the text
        };
```

And my Table Component

```js
                            <BootstrapTable
                                className="bsTable"
                                striped={true}
                                hover={true}
                                keyField='id'
                                data={this.state.currentlyDisplayed}
                                columns={columns}
                                pagination={ paginationFactory(options) }
                                filter={ filterFactory({delay:100}) }
                                fetchInfo={{dataTotalSize: this.state.currentlyDisplayed.length}}
                            />
```

Any ideas? I click it to hopefully see 5,10, All but its not responsive. I have more than 5 records in my table too...

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.show.react-bs-table-sizePerPage-dropdown ul:last-child {
  display: block;
}
```